# Fancybox Jquery Opens in Blank Page

Tags: jquery

I am using Fancybox for the first time and I cannot seem to get it working.

I have followed the instructions on the site, copy/pasted all of the .js links from their site, into mine. Still, when I click on the link that is supposed to open in the box, it instead launches in a blank page.

Clearly I'm missing something. Just cannot see what it is. Any ideas?

Thank You!

Comment: Check the console.  I've seen that happen with cross origin issues, or a page that fails to load.

Comment: No errors reported. Also tried testing the solution in various browsers. Same deal...

Comment: Post a jsfiddle of your code so we can see if we spot anything wrong